# Python: upsampling with reverse-sum operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I want to resample a column dataframe - namely, I want to upsample it in the reverse of a `sum()` style operation, assuming that each point is even. I don't particularly care about the value of the final point - for my case, it's irrelevant.

Here is a simplistic version:

```
   Input  Output
0   10.0    3.33
1    NaN    3.33
2    NaN    3.33
3   24.0    6.00
4    NaN    6.00
5    NaN    6.00
6    NaN    6.00
7   15.0   15.00
```

Is there a clean/pythonic way of doing this? I haven't managed to find anything like this in resampling libraries, but wanted to ask more experienced people before I hack together an iterative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform` by `mean`:

```
df['Input'].fillna(0).groupby(df['Input'].notna().cumsum()).transform('mean')

0     3.333333
1     3.333333
2     3.333333
3     6.000000
4     6.000000
5     6.000000
6     6.000000
7    15.000000
Name: Input, dtype: float64
```

Where,

```
df['Input'].notna().cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
Name: Input, dtype: int64
```

The idea here is to compute the mean of the non-null value inclusive of all the null cells following it and broadcast the result back to the input. We need the `fillna` call here because `mean` will ignore NaNs by default.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from cs95. Here's the same in the form of a function:

```
def reverse_sum(resampler):
    s = resampler.asfreq()
    return s.fillna(0).groupby(s.notna().cumsum()).transform('mean')
```

This makes it possible to monkeypatch pandas so it works with `.resample()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.resample import Resampler
setattr(pd.core.resample.Resampler, "reverse_sum", reverse_sum)
```

Test:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, -2], index=pd.period_range(start='2012-01-01', end='2012-01-03', freq='D'))
# 2012-01-01    1
# 2012-01-02    2
# 2012-01-03   -2

s.resample('12H').reverse_sum()

# 2012-01-01 00:00    0.5
# 2012-01-01 12:00    0.5
# 2012-01-02 00:00    1.0
# 2012-01-02 12:00    1.0
# 2012-01-03 00:00   -1.0
# 2012-01-03 12:00   -1.0
```